# Term order for complex Abstract Syntax Tree

Tags: prolog, iso-prolog

I have a question about abstract syntax trees.
In particular I want to sort several trees with an particular
term order.

How can one define a term order for an AST with the following properties:

1. For allmost all terms, the order behaves exactly
   like the standard built-in order of terms.
2. Deeply nested in the AST there are terms of functor
   pos/6 which denote source-positions.
   These functors should be ignored in the term order, i.e. all terms of  functor pos should compare as equal.

Is is possible to extend the built-in term-order with
a special case for 'pos' ?

What is the most efficient solution, what is the most
readable solution ?

Maybe I should also mention that our ASTs can be quite big, I just benchmarked one AST, which has 217479 proper functors (ignoring the nullary atoms)

Comment: Maybe I should also mention that our ASTs can be quite big, I just benchmarked one AST, which has 217479 proper functors (ignoring the nullary atoms)

Answer (score 4):

I would define a relation `ast_without_pos`/2 that relates an AST `A0` to a term `A` that is the same as `A0` except that all pos/6 subterms are replaced by the same term, say the atom `t`, and then use the standard term order on these resulting terms. I think this is very readable, and also reasonably efficient.

Comment: This means that one effectively copys the complete AST, though, it is most likely that one only has to look at a few nodes to actually determine the relation between two ASTs.

Comment: You can easily write it in such a way that whatever _can_ be shared between the terms _is_ shared in memory. For example: ast_without_pos(X, Y) :- X = something_different_from_pos, !, Y = X. etc.

Comment: Actually every node in the AST carries information about the source-location, so there is a pos-sub-term in every node and there are not many opportunities for sharing. Is there a way to do it that ressembles Haskell laziness, i.e only computes the terms that are needed?

Comment: Even without laziness: The resulting term will already be significantly smaller if all pos/6 subterms are replaced by a single atom. I find it improbable that you are exactly at such a memory boundary that you can represent the original terms, but not 2 significantly smaller additional "copies".

Comment: Ok, it would be possible concerning the memory overhead, but it still seems be slow to make a complete copy, just to look at a small fraction of the nodes.

Comment: The same for speed: Comparison already is a linear operation, so is copying.

Comment: Yes, the worst case complexity is linear. (That is the case that both ASTs are indeet identical). I want to sort a list of ASTs of which I know that they are all different and its also very likely that they differ on a position close to the root node.

Comment: Well then you can easily write a comparison predicate and use for example predsort/3. In my opinion, instead of discussing this further, you should actually try it out, the simplest approach (which I think I outlined above) first, and if that is too slow, try other ways.

Answer (score 2):

You could look at Zippers over the AST?

Here is an example over lists:

http://blog.logtalk.org/2013/04/zipper-lists-in-prolog/

If you get the sources for Termite, I think you will find a more general implementation over trees.

http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/adrian/termite/Manual/Contents.html

Any help to you?